# Want to create two Stores or Websites in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a website in magento with two different stores like Men and Women.

I dont want to show Men products in women and Women's in men.

I have created stores but when I search the products then all products show in the Result, that is wrong.

Now I have created a new site in Mangento admin. I am unable to run that site. Please help me what is the good procedure. If store is good then How can I show my products under only its store and if multi-site is good then How I can run multi-site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple store with single magento installation:

step1:

If we want to access different store view,we will create one root category (example:secondsite_rootcategory)

note:once the category is selected, under the General information set Is Active to yes and under the Display settings tab, set Is Anchor to yes.

step2:

Then Go to admin->system->manage stores

```
i) Select create website button and enter the following details
    Name:domain name of the new website         (ex:www.secondsite.com/secondemagento)
    Code:any key word for our site(without white_space) (ex:seconddomainmagento)

ii) Select manage store option under the option system->manage stores and enter
    website: select your second site name (ex:www.secondsite.com/secondmagento)
    Name: same as the second website name
    Root category: Select your root category
iii) Select create store view under the option system->manage stores

Enter the following details
    store: select your store name (ex:seconddomainmagento)
    name: Enter store view name
    code:enter store view name code(ex:secondstoreviewcode)
    status:Enabled
```

step 3: 
       create new directory
        (In this example create directory secondmagento and copy the index.php and .htaccess from root directory )
        (If same domain means create sub_directory under the magento root directory and copy index.php and .htaccess)
        edit index.php:

```
$mageFilename='app/Mage.php';
```

line to

```
$mageFilename='../app/Mage.php';
```

Some of the time it looks like

```
$mageFilename=MAGENTO_ROOT.'/app/Mage.php';
```

so we need to edit like

```
$mageFilename='../app/Mage.php';
```

then edit

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
```

line to

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'Enter your store view code here(ex:secondstoreviewcode)';
```

edit .htaccess:
add line to .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base";
        SetEnvIf Host .*magento_site_2.*MAGE_RUN_TYPE="enter your sitecode here(ex:secondomainmagento)";
```

step 4: 
         Goto system->configuration->web.
In the left side change the value of current configuration scope(that means select your second site url)
            under the Unsecurebaseurl and base secureurl tab type your second site url.

```
        Finally clear your Cache.
```

Comment: Should I have to Install two magento...? I have created two root categories and add some products under each category and website. But now I am unable to front view of one of my site.

Comment: No you can create multiple websites using same admin panel(Single magento installtion). Refer given link

Comment: I have change unsecure url for both sites. But it is giving me 404 error.

Comment: did you create the new directory which has the name of your second website in your magento root directory??

Comment: Yes I have created and I have put index.php and htaccess file there but this is showing first website not second one.
First site-http://travellersklub.com/staging/21roses/
Second Site-http://travellersklub.com/staging/21roses/women/

Comment: Is this work for multi-site? I am getting 500 Internal Server Error. Using multi-site with this method.

Comment: Yes.. 500 internal server error means error related with permission

Comment: SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base";
SetEnvIf Host .*women.*MAGE_RUN_TYPE="women";

This code gives error. When I remove this then this show 404 error.

Comment: yes. What is the file permission of your women folder

Comment: Its 755 for women folder

Comment: ok.. Can you try to change it to 777 for second website folder and their index.php, .htaccess... don't forget to clear cache

Comment: Internal Server Error again after changing permission 755 to 777

Comment: I have changed women directory and its files permission to 755. Now I am getting only 404 error. I have also removed (SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base"; SetEnvIf Host .*women.*MAGE_RUN_TYPE="women";) code from .htaccess file

Comment: the condition is directory name is equal to host and run type value in your .htaccess

Comment: What should the condition for these two links(first is working)
 First site-travellersklub.com/staging/21roses Second Site-travellersklub.com/staging/21roses/women

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need to create new directories, copy `index.php` nor alter `.htaccess` at all.**

---

- If you want to keep products separated in their respective stores then you must define websites in *System > Manage Stores*.  I shall illustrate what the table should look like.

  ```
  +----------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
  | Website Name   | Store Name                       | Store View Name   |
  +----------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
  | Mens Website   | Mens Store                       | Mens Store View   |
  | (Code: men)    | (Root Category: Mens Products)   | (Code: men)       |
  +----------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
  | Womens Website | Womens Store                     | Womens Store View |
  | (Code : women) | (Root Category: Womens Products) | (Code: women)     |
  +----------------+----------------------------------+-------------------+
  ```

  Notice there are two root categories to help you organise products, but that isn't strictly necessary to make it work.
- Now when you edit products there will be a "Websites" tab which allows you to select either "Mens Website" or "Womens Website".  This is what prevents products from showing in the wrong search so be careful not to check both boxes.
- Next go to *System > Configuration > Web* and in the scope drop-down box in the top left corner, choose "Mens Website".  Set the appropriate secure and unsecure base URLs, like `http://men.example.com/`.  Do the same for "Womens Website" and `http://women.example.com/`.
- Lastly configure DNS settings for the domains you want to use.  If you cannot do this yourself ask your web host for help.  To keep things short I'll assume you know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

i found easy in this method                                                     How To Setup Magento Powered Store using Sub-directory Method

Suppose you want to setup multiple stores under different sub-directories on the same server then you should follow this method. In this method you will have one primary domain and you will call you additional store by calling the sub-directory in the URL. i.e.

```
   Mainstore.com/store1
   Maninstore.com/store2
```

Follow the steps given below:

Login to your site via SSH, and create a subdirectory where your second store will be:
        cd public_html
    mkdir mystore1/
    cd mystore1/
Copy the index.php and .htaccess file from the directory where Magento is installed, which would be in our root web directory:
1
cp ../public_html/index.php ../public_html/.htaccess
Open up the index.php file that we just copied over and replace the following line of code:
1
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
with the following:

1
$mageFilename = '../public_html/app/Mage.php';
With the index.php file still open, replace the following line of code:
1
Mage::run();
with the following:

1
Mage::run('mystore1', 'website');

and allso you should copy app folder in the sub dirctory